# Parsing ASCII value containing commas

Tags: c++, parsing

I have one ascii  `unsigned char *` value which have value like this:

```
"1.657e-01,4.8552e-01,8.7585e-01"
```

I want to parse this value and transform this value into 3 `double` values.
Currently I am doing it with a long process:

1. Casting this value into String string `temp_S(reinterpret_cast<char *>(ascii_value));`
2. Finding all the occurrences of `,` and then making sub-string.
3. Transforming those sub-strings to double using `stod` function.

   - Is this right and safe way to do this?
   - Is there is any other way to directly parse and transforming the values to double from ASCII?

Comment: The tag "unsigned" is definitely misplaced here, there is no specifics on `char` type. Please remove it. Also "ascii" is suspicious. I suggest "C" and "input parsing".

Comment: If you're using `reinterpret_cast<char *>(ascii_value)`, you are not using a C compiler; that is pure C++.

Comment: `double x[3]; if ( 3 == scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &x[0], &x[1], &x[2]) ) { /* do something with result */`

Answer (score 2):

`strtod()` from `<stdlib.h>` returns with parsed value and pointer to next character after the value text. You can make a cycle around it and `strspn()` to skip commas.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `reinterpret_cast<>`, I assume you actually have a C++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s("1.657e-01,4.8552e-01,8.7585e-01");
    vector<double> data;
    for (istringstream iss(s); ; ) {
        double x;
        iss >> x;
        if ( ! iss) {
            cout << "Parse error" << endl;
            break;
        }
        data.push_back(x);
        char comma = 0;
        iss >> comma;
        if ( ! iss)
            break;
        if (',' != comma) {
            cout << "What is [" << comma << "]?" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Parsed " << data.size() << " pieces of data" << endl;
}
```

- http://ideone.com/rWXP57